# passing array into view (codeigniter )

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, web

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#21 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "cvxzcvd"
    ["con"]=>
    string(10) "gvsdvgsdfg"
    ["is_important"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["date"]=>
    string(3) "123"
    ["image"]=>
    string(2) "55"
    ["cat_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#22 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "fsdf"
    ["con"]=>
    string(9) "dfdsfvfds"
    ["is_important"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["date"]=>
    string(4) "5145"
    ["image"]=>
    string(7) "5454124"
    ["cat_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

I passed this array into a view

```
$this->load->view('home/index',$news_data);
```

but I wanna use the data separately.
I mean if I wanna use the second title
or the second data.
how can I express that in the view

thanks

Comment: `$news_data[1]`

Comment: How are you getting the array via database model function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go like this:-

```
$news_data[1]->title;
$news_data[1]->data;
```

Comment: thank you for answering. but  it didn't work

Message: Undefined variable: news_data

Answer (score 1):

Store the array into variable like

> $news_data['arr'] = { } ;

,and in view file access it by $arr;

> print_r($arr);